# How can I calculate fast how many times a number needs to be divided by 2 to get its binary form?

Tags: binary

If I wanted to know how many times the number x needs to be divided by 2 to get its binary form, is there a formula to calculate it?   I can't find one.

Comment: I think it will help if you give some examples where you give the number and the calculation you want.

Comment: It's the number of binary digits the number has ($\pm 1$), which is related to its binary logarithm $\log_2$. Is taking log "fast" enough?

Comment: so if I want to calculate how many steps for the decimal number 10240 binary form has 14 digits and I have to calculate $\log_210240 +1$ which means it would take 14 steps? waw thanks